# Why this code not work

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1  
Dim i = 0  
Dim re = True  
Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Timer.Tick  
    If i = 225 Then  
        re = False  
    ElseIf i = 0 Then  
        re = True  
    End If  
    If re = True Then  
        i += i  
    ElseIf re = False Then  
        i -= i
    End If  
    color1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i)  
End Sub  
End Class
```

In this code, i want the label from black to white and then from white to black.
I set the re var to indicate whether it is white, then i will reduce until the color to black. => Not works

Comment: Try stepping your code sometimes. Putting a breakpoint at the beginning at the function, and stepping through it probably would have allow you to find the typing mistakes yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i += i
```

Should be:

```
i += 1
```

`i` starts at `0`, so you keep adding `0+0` and never get anywhere.
Also, RGB colors go all the way to 255, not 225, but you would have seen that one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you have enabled timer Timer somewhere else in your code. Also, do what Kobi said, change `i += i` to `i += 1`.

What's also important is to start using `Option Strict On`, `Option Explicit On` and declaring the types of your variables:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0  
Dim re As Boolean = True
```

This is the first step to improve your code quality.

Comment: There are many issues with this code: `i` should be `shade`, `re` should probably be `increasingSahde`, and `if increasingSahde then`. I can think of a few more.

Comment: Thanks, but i am not english, so i just make a random var name :(